# Predicate being ignored in core data fetch request

Tags: core-data, predicate, nsfetchrequest

Can anyone tell me why the questionFetch predicate below is being ignored and the questionResults.count being returned is the number of rows in the entire data set?  There are only 2 rows in the data set with a questionType equal to 0, which should be the only two rows returned.  Instead all 88 rows of data are being returned.

```
let questionFetch: NSFetchRequest<Question> = Question.fetchRequest()
questionFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %i”,
    #keyPath(Question.questionType), currentQuestionType)
let questionResults = try 
    modelController.coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(questionFetch)
print("questionResults.count: ", questionResults.count)
```

Note that I have also tried with the hard-coded value in the comparison to make sure that the problem is not due to an incorrect value in the currentQuestionType variable.

```
questionFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == 0”, 
    #keyPath(Question.questionType))
```

Yet the choiceFetch predicate below, with nearly identical logic, is limiting the results appropriately.

```
let choiceFetch: NSFetchRequest<Choice> = Choice.fetchRequest()
choiceFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %i", 
    #keyPath(Choice.questionID), currentQuestionID)
let choiceResults = try managedContext.fetch(choiceFetch)
print("choiceResults.count: ", choiceResults.count)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the questionType attribute a string or number?

Comment: questionType is an int, just as questionID is an int in the second code block.